# Graphviz: Is there a way to force a node to the bottom?

Tags: attributes, constraints, graph, graphviz

I'm building a CFG (Context-free grammar), and I'd like the exit node to always be at the bottom of the graph. Sometimes it happens naturally, sometimes it doesn't.

Example:

```
digraph G {
  0;
  1;
  4;
  5;
  7;
  8;
  0 -> 4;
  5 -> 7;
  7 -> 8;
  7 -> 1;
  8 -> 5;
  4 -> 7;
}
```

Draws (using dot):

[image]

Node 1 is my exit node, I'd like that to be at the bottom. Suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use rank specification for the subgraph. In this case **sink** should make it at the bottom and **max** will make it on the same level as 5:

```
digraph G {
  0;
  { rank = sink; 1; }
  5;
  4;
  7;
  8;
  0 -> 4;
  5 -> 7;
  7 -> 8;
  7 -> 1;
  8 -> 5;
  4 -> 7;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. This also clarified how rank is supposed to be used, which I obviously misunderstood. I've solved another problem using rank=same after this. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

In [DOT](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/command.html)  try the option "-y"

```
-y          - Invert y coordinate in output
```

Comment: That builds a blank graph for me. But the description implies I should be getting my graph upside-down, which is not what I want. I want to pull "1" out from the strongly-connected component.